# Saving numbers into a file

Tags: python

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ")
sentence = sentence.lower().split()
uniquewords = []
for word in sentence:
    if word not in uniquewords:
        uniquewords.append(word)

positions = [uniquewords.index(word) for word in sentence]

recreated = " ".join([uniquewords[word] for word in positions])

positions = [x+1 for x in positions]
print uniquewords
print positions
print recreated

file = open('task2file1.txt', 'w')
file.write('\n'.join(uniquewords))
file.close()

file = open('task2file2.txt', 'w')
file.write('\n'.join(positions))
file.close()
```

This is the code I have so far and everything works except saving the positions into a textfile, the error message I get is

```
"file.write('\n'.join(positions))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found"
```

Comment: Did you try pasting the error message into a Google search?

Answer (score 3):

The `.join()` method can only join string lists. You must convert the `int`s in your `position` list to strings:

```
file.write('\n'.join(str(p) for p in positions))
```

or

```
file.write('\n'.join(map(str, positions)))
```

Comment: Cheers this helped a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Convert `positions` to a list of strings.

```
file.write('\n'.join(str(p) for p in positions))
```